# How to create image view in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6

I am New Person in drupal,
i using drupal 6, i want to create a images view like title,image, & content,
i want to develop like the image displayed hare
pl. Provide me to some guideline by images view
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id want to make something like this:

[image]

Please refer to this link. It has something that you want to achieve:

> http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/creating-a-photo-gallery-in-drupal-6/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.